# AngularJS table resized with filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, html-table

I have a table and a search bar which will filter the table's data.

My problem is that when I type in the search bar a word, the size of certain column will resize. It will then make some weird animation (resizing) while typing...

Is there a solution in css or in angularjs to make this table un-resizable?

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback  has-feedback-left search-bar">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" >
    <i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>Effort</td>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>Possible</td>
            <td>Comments</td>
            <td>description</td>
            <td>Selected {{totalSelected}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="bb in babies | filter: search">
            <td>{{bb.name}}</td>
            <td>{{bb.effort}}</td>
            <td>{{bb.Value}}</td>
            <td>{{bb.possible}}</td>
            <td>{{bb.comments}}</td>
            <td>{{bb.description}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="change(bb.id)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like `reflow` issue. When you start typing in search bar, make it `position:absolute;` so it won't affect the table. else make the columns width fixed.

Comment: If you could share the code, we can suggest better answer

Comment: I added the code (table + search bar)
For the fixed column width, they all have different size and I would like to keep this auto

Answer (score 0):

Setting fixed column width in css should solve the problem.